# Exchange 2013 NDR attack

Tags: exchange-2013, ndr

Recently I setup an exchange server 2013 sp1 on windows 2012 R2 and now it is under reverse ndr attack. I just have one server with Mailbox server role and CAS role on it.

I don't want to disable ndr of my exchange server. Is there any other way round to stop this spam?

Do I need an Edge Transport server if I want to add a recipient white list?